# How to add crt filepath for ConsumeMQTT in nifi processor

Tags: apache-nifi

Currently I am adding ca filepath into my mqtt server. To consume or publish I need to add this certificate into nifi processor, but I could not find any option for adding certicate in nifi.

[image]

So I tried to add one certificate property, but throwing error.

Answer (score 0):

@Chintamani You should import your certs into keystore or truststore for your SSL Context Service.

For Example:

```
 /usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/keytool -import -file certificate.cer -alias nifi -keystore truststore.jks

/usr/jdk64/jdk1.8.0_112/bin/keytool -import -trustcacerts -alias nifi -file certificate.cer -keystore keystore.jks
```

I usually put the files in /etc/nifi/ssl/ and be sure to chown them to nifi:nifi.  Then in your controller service, put the path to the files, the type (JKS),  the password.

https://nifi.apache.org/docs/nifi-docs/components/org.apache.nifi/nifi-ssl-context-service-nar/1.5.0/org.apache.nifi.ssl.StandardRestrictedSSLContextService/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can't provide the certificate file to Nifi directly. You'll need to create a keystore or truststore that contains your certificate or a certificate higher in the certification path. For instance, if certificate A signed certificate B and certificate B signed your certificate, you could add certificate A or B or your certificate to a truststore. Let's say you used LetsEncrypt.org to sign your certificate. You could browse to LetsEncrypt.org and download their certificate and add that to your truststore. Once you have the certificate file, you can add it to an existing truststore or **create a new one** in one command using the Java `Keytool` (available with a JDK or JRE):

```
keytool -import -alias YOUR_ALIAS -file CERTIFICATE_FILE -storetype TYPE -keystore MY_TRUST_STORE_FILE
```

For Example:

```
keytool -import -alias Chintamani_Alias -file Chintamani.cer -storetype JKS -keystore Chintamani.truststore
```

This command will create `Chintamani.truststore` with the password you provide if the file doesn't already exist. Then you provide the path to the truststore, the truststore password and set the truststore type (JKS in the example above).

And make sure:

- Your MQTT processor is using `ssl://` in the Broker Uri
- Your `StandardSSLContextService` or `StandardRestrictedSSLContextService` is enabled
- Your MQTT processor is configured to use your SSL Context Service

or you might see errors like:

```
o.a.nifi.processors.mqtt.ConsumeMQTT ConsumeMQTT[id=<GUID>] Connection to <YOUR URL>:8883 lost (or was never connected) and connection failed. Yielding processor: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
? causes: Connection lost (32109) - java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.MqttException: Connection lost
    at org.eclipse.paho.client.mqttv3.internal.CommsReceiver.run(CommsReceiver.java:190)
```